# How to convert SQL query to Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

How do I convert the following sql query to ruby on rails?

```
select health_workers.name,health_workers.surname,clinics.name as clinic,count(observations.id) as count,observations.observation_date 
from health_workers 
left join observations on health_workers.id = observations.health_worker_id, clinics 
where health_workers.clinic_id = clinics.id 
group  by health_workers.name,health_workers.surname,clinics.name,observations.observation_date.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```
query = "select health_workers.name,health_workers.surname,clinics.name as clinic,count(observations.id) as count,observations.observation_date 
from health_workers 
left join observations on health_workers.id = observations.health_worker_id, clinics 
where health_workers.clinic_id = clinics.id 
group  by health_workers.name,health_workers.surname,clinics.name,observations.observation_date."


results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

and this will gives you the result